# problem with samba4 post-instalation

Tags: samba4

i am a newbie linux enthusiastic. I recently installed samba4 on Ubuntu 13.04 but experienced post installation error

```
bobby@bobby-Aspire-4732Z:~$ sudo apt-get install samba4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
samba4 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Setting up samba4 (4.0.3+dfsg1-0.1ubuntu1) ...
ERROR(<type 'exceptions.ValueError'>): uncaught exception - unable to parse dn string
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/netcmd/__init__.py", line 175, in _run
return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/netcmd/dbcheck.py", line 108, in run
fix=fix, yes=yes, quiet=quiet, in_transaction=started_transaction)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/dbchecker.py", line 58, in __init__
self.infrastructure_dn = ldb.Dn(samdb, "CN=Infrastructure," + samdb.domain_dn())
dpkg: error processing samba4 (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 255
Errors were encountered while processing:
samba4
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
bobby@bobby-Aspire-4732Z:~$
```

Have anyone ever experienced this before and may I suggest your explanation.
Thank you before.

Regards,
Bobby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First uninstall your samba version :

```
sudo apt-get purge samba4

sudo apt-get install -f
```

Second add samba4 repository :

```
 sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kernevil/samba4/ubuntu precise main"

sudo apt-get update
```

Third install samba4 dependencies :

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential libacl1-dev libattr1-dev libblkid-dev libgnutls-dev libreadline-dev python-dev python-dnspython gdb pkg-config libpopt-dev libldap2-dev dnsutils libbsd-dev attr krb5-user docbook-xsl libcups2-dev libpam0g-dev ntp -y
```

Fourth download samba4 :

```
sudo apt-get install samba4
```

Comment: my pleasure mate , happy to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

https://sourceforge.net/projects/samba4all/

I have a few virtualbox OVA's on there and install instructions.

Personally I would search for sernet samba and download their versions.
Seems to work better